# No Transaction.from equivalent in Rust

Tags: rust, transaction, transaction-instructions

I want to be able to get my transaction from a base-64 encoded buffer to later send and confirm. I have a working example in Javascript, but I need an equivalent of the Javascript code in Rust. Here is the Javascript code:

```
const transaction = Transaction.from(
      Buffer.from(serializedTransaction, "base64")
    );
```

I have not been able to find any Rust alternative for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `bincode::deserialize` directly on the serialized transaction, ie:

```
let tx = Transaction::new_signed_with_payer(...); // do your thing here
let ser = bincode::serialize(&tx).unwrap();
let deser = bincode::deserialize(&ser).unwrap();
```

This was copied from the test at https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/blob/3922f3d68522b520d0d741d34db007483ac1cb9c/sdk/src/transaction/mod.rs#L1295-L1301